# Type inference problem when writing a generic extension method with more than one type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I am writing a generic extension method for IEnumerable for mapping a list of objects to another list of mapped objects. This is how I would like the method to work:

```
IList<Article> articles = GetArticles();
return articles.Map<ArticleViewModel>(_mappingEngine);
```

This is the method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T2> Map<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> list, IMappingEngine engine)
{
    return list.Select(engine.Map<T1, T2>);
}
```

However `articles.Map<ArticleViewModel>(_mappingEngine);`  gives a compile error.
The problem is that the type inference for T1 doesn't work. I have to **explicitly** call it like this instead:

```
articles.Map<Article, ArticleViewModel>(_mappingEngine);
```

If I create an extension method with only one parameter T1 like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T1> DummyMap<T1>(this IEnumerable<T1> list, IMappingEngine engine)
{
    return list;
}
```

Then I can call it like this, without having to specify T1:

```
articles.DummyMap(_mappingEngine);
```

Is there are reason why the compiler can't infer the type of T1 in the extension method for Map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The problem is that the type inference for T1 doesn't work

Actually, the problem isn't T1 - it is T2; return types are not used in this inference. So you can't do that. One option might be a fluent API, for example:

```
return articles.Map(_mappingEngine).To<SomeT2>();
```

with something like:

```
public static MapProjection<T1> Map<T1>(this IEnumerable<T1> list, IMappingEngine engine)
{
    return new MapProjection<T1>(list, engine);
}
public class MapProjection<T1>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T1> list;
    private readonly IMappingEngine engine;
    internal MapProjection( IEnumerable<T1> list, IMappingEngine engine)
    {this.list = list; this.engine = engine;}

    public IEnumerable<T2> To<T2>()
    {
        return list.Select(engine.Map<T1, T2>());
    }
}
```

assuming that the interface is something like:

```
public interface IMappingEngine {
    Func<T1, T2> Map<T1, T2>();
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however I am still curious as to why the inference won't work on my case. Shouldn't the compiler search for all matching generic extension methods which have T1 as first parameter?

Comment: @Can if you specify the generic parameters, it is all-or-nothing. There was discussion around supporting "mumble" typing here, i.e. something like `Map<?,ArticleViewModel>(...)` (meaning: you figure out the first, I'm telling you the second), but that is not in the language at current.

Comment: @Marc, I believe I've answered him. In conclusion, the "why?" it's just a language implementation detail, it can't have some great answer, can have?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. I was thinking it would try to evaluate  Map<ArticleViewModel> as Map<*,ArticleViewModel> as well, but I can see how that could cause ambiguity. Thanks!

Comment: @Can - the problem there is: you can have `Foo()`, `Foo<T>()` and `Foo<T1,T2>()` - it would need special logic to figure out which you mean.

Comment: +1. @SLaks gave me an similar answer to a similar question, and wrote a blog post about it: [partial-type-inference-in-net](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/partial-type-inference-in-net.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want C# compiler to infer type of T1 even if you provide T2 without providing T1.

The point is you can use type inference, or just don't use it. You can't mix both worlds:

```
    public void M<T, S>(T t, S s)
    {
    }

    M<string>("hello", "world!")
```

This code doesn't compile, but:

```
    public void M<T, S>(T t, S s)
    {
    }

    M("hello", "world!")
```

..compiles.

Comment: I want it infer T1, not T2. T1 is the type the method is based on (i.e. IEnumerable<Article> in my example.)

Comment: It's almost the same. T1, T2 or T1000 (no, it's not Terminator...). You can't mix both worlds. You use type inference or you avoid it :D