# Compile time generics syntax

Tags: c#, generics

```
class GenericWrapper<T>
{   
}

class WrapperInstance : GenericWrapper<string>
{   
}

class Usage
{
    public static Usage Create<T1, T2> (T2 t2) where T1 : GenericWrapper<T2>
    {
        return null;
    }
}

...

// works
Usage.Create<WrapperInstance, string>("bar");

// doesnt work
Usage.Create<WrapperInstance>("bar");
```

I suspect the answer is no, but is there a way I can make the last line compile?

I want the compiler to force me to provide a string argument without having to know or first go and examine `WrapperInstance` to see what `T` of `GenericWrapper` it implements.

I know I can make it compile by either using the first method or by taking `object` as the argument and doing runtime checking, but thats not the question ;) I largely suspect these are my only two options.

Thanks

Comment: Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243357/type-inference-problem-when-writing-a-generic-extension-method-with-more-than-one/5243446#5243446

Comment: It will not work due to limitations of C#. But if you tell more about what you want to archive, there might be a nicer way to write it down. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect the answer is no, but is there a way I can make the last line compile?

No. `Create` has two generic type parameters. You either specify none or you specify both. In the case of none, the compiler will try to infer the types from the invocation arguments. However, in this case it can not because `T1` never appears in the argument list. Therefore you must specify both.

Comment: I believe there's no need of explaining more the reasons. See my comment in the question, which was a long discussion about almost same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

- You want to infer just one type argument, and specify the other. You can't do that with normal type inference. However, you *could* make `Usage` generic, thus specifying *one* type argument there, and letting the *other* be inferred using the generic method:

  ```
  Usage<WrapperInstance>.Create("foo");
  ```

  That's something I've often done before, but that just leads to the second problem...
- The type parameter you want to specify (T1) is constrained by the one you want to infer (T2). The above example can't do that, as `Usage<WrapperInstance>` doesn't "have" a T2 to validate... and you can't constrain an *existing* type parameter on a generic method - only ones which are introduced in the method.

There's one way I think we *could* do this:

```
public class Usage
{
    public static Usage<T2> For<T2>(T2 t2)
    {
        return new Usage<T2>(t2);
    }
}

public class Usage<T2>
{
    private readonly T2 t2; // Assuming we need it

    public Usage(T2 t2)
    {
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    // I don't know what return type you really want here
    public static Foo Create<T1>() where T1 : GenericWrapper<T2>
    {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
Usage.Foo("bar").Create<WrapperInstance>();
```

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I don't know whether or not that's helpful - but it *does* manage to accomplish what you were after in terms of:

- Validating the `WrapperInstance` type argument
- Inferring the `string` type argument

Comment: hmm thanks thats an interesting approach. I wanted to be able to specify T1, and then be prompted for an instance of T2 without having to "know" what T2 is (i.e. not have to know what T T1 extends in the T1 : X<T> situation)

Comment: @Andrew: Unfortunately you can't do that, because T1 is constrained in terms of T2 rather than the other way round.